# Postman post request response is coming with null parameters

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I am trying to execute  stored procedure for inserting the values into tables by using the ExecuteSqLRaw() in the Service class.

```
public Category AddCategory(Category category)
     {

         db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("[dbo].[CatinsertSP] {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}", category.CategoryId, category.CategoryCode, category.CategoryName, category.AboutCategory, category.ParentCategoryId, category.IsEnable, category.IsActive, category.IsBlock);
         return category;
     }
```

This is the request body in Postman
{
"Category_Code":"130",
"Category_Name":"Kids"
}

This is the response with status 200
{
"categoryId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"categoryCode": null,
"categoryName": null,
"aboutCategory": null,
"parentCategoryId": null,
"isEnable": null,
"isActive": null,
"isBlock": null,
"updateLog": null,
"createdOn": null,
"createdBy": null,
"updateOn": null,
"updateBy": null,
"seqNo": 0,
"module": [],
"product": []
}
This is stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CatinsertSP] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Category_Id uniqueidentifier ,
    @Category_Code nvarchar(20),
    @Category_Name nvarchar(167),
    @About_Category nvarchar(max),
    @Parent_Category_Id uniqueidentifier,
    @Is_Enable bit,
    @Is_Active bit,
    @Is_Block bit
    
    
    
AS
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into [dbo].[Category] (Category_Id,Category_Code,Category_Name,About_Category,Parent_Category_Id,Is_Enable,Is_Active,Is_Block) values(newid(),@Category_Code,@Category_Name,@About_Category,@Parent_Category_Id,@Is_Enable,@Is_Active,@Is_Block)
    select * from Category where Category_Id=@Category_Id
     


END
Go
```

This is controller code`

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Category> AddCategory([FromBody]Category category)
        {
            return _service.AddCategory(category);
        }
```

I do not understand that the problem is with the postman or in calling the stored procedure?
I am new to this ,please help.